# Can't use 'rails' command after installing using gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems

I've installed rails using 'gem install rails', but when I try to create a new project, I get the error:
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

There were no error messages when I ran 'gem install rails'. How come I cannot run rails commands?

When I do sudo apt-get install rails, it will install an older version of ruby, 1.8. I want the newest, so I do not want to install rails from apt-get.

Edit:
Figured it out.
Had to add PATH="${PATH}:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/" to .bashrc

Comment: Are you using RVM? It looks like the gemset is not loaded. Does 'gem list' give you rails ?

Comment: Yes, I have rails (3.2.1) listed. When I type "gem rails", I get this error: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command rails

Comment: you should try rvm for a cleaner install of rails (https://rvm.io//)

Comment: I actually am using RVM. I think maybe the order or the configuration that I have is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for rails is not 'gem rails' it is just 'rails'

To install rails:

```
gem install rails
```

To create a new rails application

```
rails myapp
```

Comment: I know, this was my original question. This is what I get: The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails, the problem is that I did do gem install rails

Answer (score 0):

reboot your machine, this sometimes happens to me on Ubuntu, 99% of the time I just need to rebort

Comment: Damn, sorry. What output do you get when you run `rvm list` and `which rails`

Comment: I got it working. I added the solution to my original post. Thank you for attempting the solution.

Answer (score -1):

> The command for rails is not 'gem rails' it is just 'rails'
>
> To install rails:
>
> gem install rails To create a new rails application
>
> **rails new myapp**

Comment: OP did not try to run `gem rails`.